# Remove AppBarLayout Below Shadow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-appbarlayout

I'm not able to remove AppBarLayout below shadow i used below code

app:elevation="0dp"

in both AppBarLayout  and Toolbar but it's not working for me. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. [image]

Comment: set app:elevation="0dp"

Comment: namespace xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" and not android one

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question is pointing to same problem Android appbarlayout elevation appears in status bar

Possible solutions:
Your root layout should have android:fitsSystemWindows="true" at all times, otherwise your UI will not draw behind status bar.

Now wrap the AppBarLayout inside another CoordinatorLayout which has

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false".
```

This will prevent the shadow from overflowing into statusbar.

or 
**Add elevation 0dp to AppBarLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
 android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 app:elevation="0dp">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set elevation as 0 for toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:elevation="0dp"  />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```